# Javascript - if submenu exist

Tags: javascript, menu

I have menu like:

```
<ul class="product-categories">
 <li>
  <a href="http://...">Test</a>
   <ul class="children">
    <li><a href="http://...">Test2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://...">Test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And script:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.product-categories>li>ul').hide();
    if (jQuery('.product-categories>li').find('ul.children').length > 0) {
        jQuery(this).find('a').removeAttr('href');
        jQuery('.product-categories>li').on('click', function () {
            jQuery(this).find('ul').slideToggle(500)
                .siblings().find('ul:visible').slideUp(500);
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
        });
    }
});
```

I had problem with javascript. I want to see if submenu than it's remove link from parent li and show/hide submenu on click. Someone can help with that code ?

If i change:

```
jQuery(this).find('a').removeAttr('href');
```

to:

```
jQuery('.product-categories>li>a').removeAttr('href');
```

it's remove Attr `href` for all parent `li` links, not only where if work.

I just create code (and show/hide work but i don't know how to delete link only when submenu):

```
    jQuery('.product-categories>li>ul').hide();
jQuery('.product-categories>li').children('a').removeAttr('href');      
jQuery('.product-categories>li').on('click',function(){
  if (jQuery(this).find('ul.children').length > 0) {
    jQuery(this).find('ul').slideToggle(500)
           .siblings().find('ul:visible').slideUp(500);
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: Which element uses class `.product-categories`?

Comment: `jQuery('ul li ul').prev('a').removeAttr('href')`?

Comment: putvande that what i search ! Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this: `jQuery('ul li ul').prev('a').removeAttr('href')`.
It checks if you have nested `ul` and removes the attribute from the `a` tag previous to that `ul`.